# Access SQL from a cloud function in another project

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

My situation is simple.

I have a Google Cloud Function in Project A accessing a PostgreSQL instance in Project A. It works great.

Now I need another Google Cloud Function from project B to access the PostgreSQL instance in project A.

I have been staring at [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions) in Google documentation and I just can't parse it:

> If the authorizing service account belongs to a different project than the Cloud SQL instance, enable the Cloud SQL Admin API, and add the IAM permissions listed above, on both projects.

I understand that the service account for my Cloud Function in Project B needs to have the IAM permissions. (If so, is it possible to restrict the Cloud SQL permissions only to the database in Project A?)

Do I understand correctly that I need to:

- Create a service account in Project A (where the SQL lives) that has the same IAM permissions
- Add the service account from Project B as a principal to the service account in Project A?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to create a new service account, analyse it like this: `Project A` have to allow the access to `project B`. As the cloud functions use the *App Engine default service account*, you have to allow this account (from `project B`) in the project where your database runs (`Project A`).

So:

**On project B:**

- Enable the sql API, you can click [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https://console.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.110250053.1509594595.1642439772-547169477.1642439772) to do that `->` choose `project B`.
- Enable cloud Functions api;
- In IAM section, copy the email of the App Engine default service account:`<PROJECT_B_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

**On project A (where postgresql resides):**

- Add `Cloud SQL Client` role to App Engine default service account *(Name=App Engine default service account)* of `project B`, which is something like this `<PROJECT_B_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: I've done this and double checked but still am unable to connect to my firebase webapp to my google cloud postgresql database.

Comment: @boredProjects remeber to enable Cloud SQL Admin API in project B, and use  either `Unix sockets` or `Cloud SQL connector` to connect.